# bootstrap 4 nav-tabs change active background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I change the `:active` white background state to an underline every time the user clicks a tab? I've done this in bootstrap 3 but its no longer working in 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just style the pseudo class, so for example

```
.navbar:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

if for some reason it conflicts with an existing style you can always throw `!important` at the end

Comment: not working hmmm the default is still a white background